# C# - Process.Start() The Operation was cancelled by the user

Tags: c#, .net, process.start

Pardon my lack of any proper formatting here, but I *desperately* need a solution to this one problem I hadn't even known existed up until this point.

While running Process.Start(); I run in to this problem:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The operation was canceled by the user
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String fileName)
at WorkDamnit.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

No matter why I try I can never seem to solve this issue. It doesn't seem to be based on my code (seen below) as I made a brand new project specifically to single out the problem (with no luck of course).

anyways, here's the culprit. I figured somebody with more experience would have better luck taking a jab at this issue. Perhaps maybe I'm missing something in my Visual Studio installation.

```
Process process1 = Process.Start("Render\\PHOENIXRender.exe");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: can you explain at what point, you get this exception? exactly at what line or step. b'coz, the same lines works for me when i try to start some app on my end. with no issues.

Comment: this project is the new one I created to attempt singling the issue out. This happens when I start the program.

Comment: Well!, it doesnt do that for the process i start on my end. i would suggest check if you can run this exe and check if there's any permission issue causing the code to run/trigger the process to start. May be, run this code from VS as admin.

Comment: I have attempted to run the program with elevated privileges to no avail. I know for a fact that this works under normal circumstances as I have done this before with the same application being launched.

Comment: actually do you think onedrive sync could be causing my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eurika! thank you to everyone who has posted a comment. It turns out the problem was related to OneDrive sync and OneDrive in general.

I am not exactly sure why this was the problem but I am glad I can move on with my work.

Comment: What a surprise... I've just been on the verge of shooting myself in the head after OneDrive decided to try and overwrite a load of my files with old versions!
Uninstalled it (cos it's rubbish...) and now I'm getting your error...

Comment: After uninstalling OneDrive, I had to restart my machine and it started working again.
Must've been some kind of permissions or setup issue that restarting resolved.